# Testem gulp task hangs after finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, gulp, testem

This gulp task doesn't exit after finished, I have to manually press
Ctrl-C to exit.

```
gulp.task('test', function(done) {
    var testem = require('testem');

    var testemOptions = {
        file: 'testem.json'
    };

    var t = new testem();

    t.startCI(testemOptions, done);
});
```

How can i make this task exit properly?

Note: Actually it exits itself, but it takes like 15 seconds after finished.

Output:

```
[15:49:59] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[15:49:59] Starting 'test'...
ok 1 PhantomJS 1.9 - Integration Tests: Home Index Page

1..3
# tests 3
# pass  3
# fail  0

# ok
[15:50:00] Finished 'test' after 1.33 s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to reproduce your problem using the `Chromium launcher`, but it's should be the same with `PhantomJS`. There is indeed a `15sec` `CPU` delay between the end of the `task` and the actual exit of the `process`.

```
> time gulp testem
Starting 'testem'...
ok 1 Chrome 32.0 - sass: link
ok 2 Chrome 32.0 - Unit - HomeRoute: exists
ok 3 Chrome 32.0 - Unit - HomeRoute: #model
ok 4 Chrome 32.0 - Unit - HomeRoute: redirect

1..4
# tests 4
# pass  4
# fail  0

# ok
Finished 'testem' after 938 ms
gulp testem  1.27s user 0.25s system 9% cpu 16.581 total
```

By removing the `done callback` you set on the task and passing to `startCI` that don't take this as parameter,

```
var testem = require('testem');

gulp.task('test', function () {

  var testemOptions = {
    file: 'testem.json'
  };

  var t = new testem();
  return t.startCI(testemOptions);

});
```

the task run as expected and exit properly on finish :

```
> time gulp testem
Starting 'testem'...
ok 1 Chrome 32.0 - sass: link
ok 2 Chrome 32.0 - Unit - HomeRoute: exists
ok 3 Chrome 32.0 - Unit - HomeRoute: #model
ok 4 Chrome 32.0 - Unit - HomeRoute: redirect

1..4
# tests 4
# pass  4
# fail  0

# ok
gulp testem  1.26s user 0.19s system 91% cpu 1.582 total
```

By the way, don't know you can do this, simply pass an object with a `file` property to `startCI`, I thought you should read the config file using `fs.readFile` and parsing its data into `JSON` to launch `testem` using the config parameters you provided inside `testem.json`.

One more thing, there is a gulp plugin, **[gulp-testem](https://github.com/sargentsurg/gulp-testem)** that I did not have the opportunity to try, but which may be helpful.

Comment: I've changed my code a little and now it's not possible to do `return t.startCI` anymore. Is there a way to use the callback function to end the gulp task and not hang too. Do you think it's a bug, i mean it's not supposed to hang is it. 

See my next question and edited code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469976/exec-node-app-hangs-inside-gulp-task